# pandas checks if the no. of true in each group is equals to 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`,

```
cluster_id    dummy
1             False
1             True
1             True
2             False
2             False
3             False
3             True
```

I want to create a boolean column 'dummy_display', which is set to `False` if there is at least one `dummy == True` in each cluster and the number of `True` values is less than the length of the cluster, so the results should look like,

```
cluster_id    dummy     dummy_display
1             False     False
1             True      False
1             True      False
2             False     True
2             False     True
3             False     False
3             True      False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `transform` with `any`

```
In [137]: ~df.groupby('cluster_id')['dummy'].transform('any')
Out[137]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
Name: dummy, dtype: bool
```

---

```
In [139]: df['dummy_display'] = ~df.groupby('cluster_id')['dummy'].transform('any')

In [140]: df
Out[140]:
   cluster_id  dummy  dummy_display
0           1  False          False
1           1   True          False
2           1   True          False
3           2  False           True
4           2  False           True
5           3  False          False
6           3   True          False
```

Comment: How does this answer deal with `the number of True values is less than the length of the cluster` ?

Answer (score 2):

#### In My Opinion...

@Zero's answer is simpler and should be the goto approach.  But I couldn't help but provide a Numpy alternative.

```
i, u = pd.factorize(df.cluster_id)
a = np.zeros(len(u), np.bool8)
np.logical_or.at(a, i, df.dummy.values)

df.assign(dummpy_display=a[i])

   cluster_id  dummy  dummpy_display
0           1  False            True
1           1   True            True
2           1   True            True
3           2  False           False
4           2  False           False
5           3  False            True
6           3   True            True
```

---

#### Breakdown

`pandas.factorize` creates an array of integers representing the unique values in `df.cluster_id`

```
i, u = pd.factorize(df.cluster_id)
print(f"factorization (i): {[*i]}\nunique values (u): {[*u]}")

factorization (i): [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
unique values (u): [1, 2, 3]
```

We then initialize `False` values for each unique `cluster_id`

```
a = np.zeros(len(u), np.bool8)
print(f"accumulated `or` init (a): {[*a]}")

accumulated `or` init (a): [False, False, False]
```

Then use the `np.logical_or.at` function to accumulate using `or` logic given specified indices and boolean values

```
np.logical_or.at(a, i, df.dummy.values)
print(f"accumulated `or` post (a): {[*a]}")
print(f"broadcast over factorization (a[i]):\n  {[*a[i]]}")

accumulated `or` post (a): [True, False, True]
broadcast over factorization (a[i]):
  [True, True, True, False, False, True, True]
```

Let's take a deeper look.  I'll iterate through and show the evolution of what happens to the grouped accumulation variable `a`

```
a = [False, False, False]
print(f"accumulate `or` init (a): {a}", end='\n\n')

d = df.assign(i=i, a=None)[['cluster_id', 'i', 'dummy', 'a']]

for j in d.index:
  a[d.at[j, 'i']] |= d.at[j, 'dummy']
  d.at[j, 'a'] = [*a]

d


   cluster_id  i  dummy                              a
            at ↓     ⇩  or a[0]          ⇩
0           1  0  False              [False, False, False]
                             ╭──────────⤴
            at ↓     ⇩  or a[0] ==       ⇩
1           1  0   True               [True, False, False]
                             ╭──────────⤴
            at ↓     ⇩  or a[0] ==       ⇩
2           1  0   True               [True, False, False]
                             ╭─────────────────⤴
            at ↓     ⇩  or a[1] ==              ⇩
3           2  1  False               [True, False, False]
                             ╭─────────────────⤴
            at ↓     ⇩  or a[1] ==              ⇩
4           2  1  False               [True, False, False]
                             ╭────────────────────────⤴
            at ↓     ⇩  or a[2] ==                     ⇩
5           3  2  False               [True, False, False]
                             ╭────────────────────────⤴
            at ↓     ⇩  or a[2] ==                     ⇩
6           3  2   True                [True, False, True]
```

And the same broadcasting we showed above

```
print(f"result (a): {a}\nbroadcasted (a[i]):\n  {[a[j] for j in i]}")

result (a): [True, False, True]
broadcasted (a[i]):
  [True, True, True, False, False, True, True]
```